# QnA bot on Microsoft Teams will not return more than one answer

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker, feedback

I've created QnA bot on Azure and integrated it with Teams. I'm built a knowledge base and it's able to return answers based on the knowledge base.

For training, I would like the bot to turn the top 5 answers regardless if there's a match. It will help me train the model if I can select which one is actually the best match.

I've updated the default responses to return the top 5 if there's no response, but I don't see where to always return the top 5 responses and invoke feedback from the user.

From the qnamakerBaseDialog.js in App Server Editor:

```
const {
    QnAMakerDialog
} = require('botbuilder-ai');

const {
    ActivityFactory
} = require('botbuilder-core');

// Default parameters
const DefaultThreshold = 0.0;
const DefaultTopN = 5;
const DefaultNoAnswer = 'No answers found. Please rephrase the question.';
```

Comment: Currently QnA service does not reply any keys if there is no match. This is by design.

Comment: There is a match. I want to return more than the top match.

Comment: There is no top match. For example when QnA returns 3 results as match, user cant retrieve top 5.

Comment: If three results are a match, how are all three shown? I'm currently getting one match? Thanks for the feedback.